# Nexus2: How can I get a list of all artifacts from a specific repository via REST API?

Tags: api, nexus, n3dr

I want to get a list (json) of all artifacts in one specific repository via the REST API.

I've already tried:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost/nexus/service/local/respositories/<reponame>/content/
```

This works, but it deliveres me a json listing all my subdirectories in this repo. But what I want is a list with all the artifacts contained in all subdirectories.

Someone knows how to do this? Is there a way to iterate through all folders? I was thinking about the search keyword, but I wouldn't know for what to search.

Comment: Do you still use nexus2 or did you upgrade to version 3?

Comment: still using nexus 2 because of various reasons... we are actually thinking to move to another repo manager instead of upgrading - blob stores are not really something exciting

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# Get status
curl http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/status 
# List of repositories
curl http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories
```

For the json parameter:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" <url>
```

More information, see this [link](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2012/07/learning-the-nexus-rest-api-read-the-docs-or-fire-up-a-browser/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer first!
But this is not what I am looking for. What I need is a list of the actual content of one  repository I want to specify... with the request I wrote I can only get to the first layer of the directory structure (the folders inside the repo). The list I need should include the contents of each folder inside the repo

Answer (score 0):

For nexu3 this how to list artifact using curl:

curl -X GET "http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/rest/v1/search?repository={repository_name}&format=maven2&maven.groupId={groupeID}&maven.artifactId={ArtifactID}&maven.extension={package_type}" -H "accept: application/json"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).